# Append is overwriting existing data in list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python program which is supposed to append list to a global variable, but instead of appending it is overwriting the list. This a demo function I made which works in the same way:

```
var_gobal = []

def parse(list_parse,stack):
    for element in list_parse:
        stack.append(element["a"])
        print(stack)
        global var_gobal
        var_gobal.append(stack)

to_parse = [{"a":"abc","b":"bcd","c":"cde"},{"a":"def","b":"efg","c":"ghi"}]
parse(to_parse,[])
print (var_gobal)
```

The expected output should be

```
[['abc'], ['abc', 'def']]
```

But instead i get

```
[['abc', 'def'], ['abc', 'def']]
```

The first element of the list is overwritten. Why is this happening?

Comment: Shouldn't `global var_global` be outside of the loop?

Comment: Same output doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use slice `stack = stack[:] + [element["a"]]` instead of `append` method of list:

```
var_gobal = []

def parse(list_parse,stack):
    global var_gobal

    for element in list_parse:
        stack = stack[:] + [element["a"]]
        print(stack)
        var_gobal.append(stack)

to_parse = [{"a":"abc","b":"bcd","c":"cde"},{"a":"def","b":"efg","c":"ghi"}]
parse(to_parse,[])
print (var_gobal)
```

Output:

```
['abc']
['abc', 'def']
[['abc'], ['abc', 'def']]
```

Or, using `stack = stack + [element["a"]]` would give same result as well.

To see the difference, we can see following example:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b']
tmp = []
global_var = [] 

for i in my_list:
    tmp.append(i)
    global_var.append(tmp)

global_var
```

This outputs `global_var` as `[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b']]`.

Although, `tmp` is appended to `global_var` in every iteration through `my_list`, on every append all referencing (*or all that are pointing*) to `tmp` is changed. Instead if `slice` or `+` is used, new list is created with all the elements in first since `[:]` is used:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b']
tmp = []
global_var = [] 

for i in my_list:
    tmp = tmp[:] + [i]
    global_var.append(tmp)

global_var
```

This results: `[['a'], ['a', 'b']]`

Comment: This is working, but why is `stack.append()` causing a problem?

Comment: similar to above case, initially stack is appended with `['abc']` and appended to `global_var` as well. But in next iteration, the same stack is appended with `def` and becomes `['abc', 'def']`. When we append this updated `stack`, all the places of `stack` is used will now have same updated value (arrays are passed by reference, here stack is just an array or list), so even previously appended `stack` gets changed.

Comment: ah ok now i understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You have to copy *stack* to the *var_global* instead of appending a reference.

```
var_gobal.append(stack.copy())
```

Comment: this gives an error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'copy'`

Comment: @PrateekGupta #Patrik you are right, but you have to write `var_gobal.append( copy(stack) )`

Comment: @PrateekGupta `list.copy()` is available from python3.3

Comment: Cleanest solution imo.

Answer (score 3):

> stack will have  2 element after second, that was saved in stack list.

```
var_gobal = []

def parse(list_parse,stack):
    for element in list_parse:
        stack.append(element["a"])
        print(stack)
        new_stack = list(stack)
        var_gobal.append(new_stack)


to_parse = [{"a":"abc","b":"bcd","c":"cde"},{"a":"def","b":"efg","c":"ghi"}]
parse(to_parse,[])
print (var_gobal)

>>> print (var_gobal)
[['abc'], ['abc', 'def']]
```

Comment: this is also working along with @open-source 's answer but why do i need to create another list? stack variable is already a list, first with 1 element then after looping with 2 elements and i am appending it to the global variable each and every time so why doesn't it stick?

Comment: It creates a copy of stack at that point time. Even if stack changes, copy of stack would still contain the previous stack values. It because the reason provide by @open-source in comments

Comment: It creates a copy of stack at that point time. Even if stack changes, copy of stack would still contain the previous stack values. It because the reason provide by @open-source in comments

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the explanation, your answer is also write but i can only accept one.

Comment: @PrateekGupta : Cool

Answer (score 0):

It's because of scope of the variable you are using, You can use `copy.deepcopy(my_dict)` so that it won't override the data you are inserting into the list